# Store value as a variable for later use CodedUI

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I wonder if someone can give me an idea, I have a feeling (google searching) that this is not possible, but there are some clever people here, so I will ask and see..

I have developed a CodedUI test to test our web application, all is working fine, but I wanted to remove some manual steps and see if they could be automated..

What I want to do it capture the value (string) from one of the pages on our site, then feed that back into the codedui test for use later, as an input..

I have been able to extract the value using a web performance test, but I can't seem to work out how to then use this in my CodedUi test, maybe there is a better way?

Hope someone has some ideas.

Thanks

Karl

Comment: Do it all in Coded UI. See how assertions are generated and how they gather text from the screen. Rather than asserting, save the text into variables. Write these text values into other on-screen fields (the technique for writing the values is explained within pages on data driving Coded UI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you found a way to capture the value. anyhow I would like to tell you the simpler hand code methods both to capture the value and to use it later on.

- **To Capture the value;**

  (1) Add the control(HtmlDiv or HtmlPane) to UIMap,

  (2) then capture the value simply as given below

  `string CapturedValue = htmlcontrol.InnerText.Trim();`

  (3) *if you want to filter the numbers from the string, then add this(optional),*

  `string filterCapturedValue = RegEx.Replace(CapturedValue.trim(),"[A-Za-z ]",string.Empty );`

Now the value is capture and stored in CapturedValue.

- **To Use this value;**

  (1) declare CapturedValue  as a public globally,

  `public string CapturedValue ="";`

  (2) Then use this wherever you want.